# Get arsinh from sinh

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

I need to establish the inverse function of the hyperbolic sine:
I am trying to do this by setting $y = \sinh(x)$ and solving for $x$, however I got stuck at this:
$$
y=\frac{e^x -e^{-x}}{2}
$$
$$
2y=e^x - e^{-x}
$$
I dont know how to solve for x at this point, though. Taking the logarithm seems nonsensical with a sum on the right side.
The end goal is the arsinh given by
$$
y = \log(x + \sqrt{x^2 +1})
$$

Comment: Note that $e^{-x} = \frac{1}{e^x}$ you have a quadratic equation in $e^x$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: make replacement $e^x = z$ and use $e^{-x} = 1 / z$ to get quadratic equation on $z$.

Comment: You mean $e^{-x}=1/z$, not $e^{-x}=z$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write $$2y=e^x-\frac{1}{e^x}$$, now substitute $$t=e^x$$ and solve the quadratic.